# React , this not function is map ,?

Tags: reactjs

this code , It gives an error that the map is not a function, I couldn't figure it out

I tried forEach this time I got ForEach undefined answer

Why am I getting this error, I couldn't figure it out, I would be very grateful if you could help.

```
import React, { useEffect ,useState} from "react";
    import Navbar from "../navbar/Navbar";
    import FrindesAdd from "../input/frindesAdd";
    import Entry from "../entry/entry"
    import { userEntry } from "../../context/EntryContext";
    import axios from "axios"
    import Cookies from "universal-cookie"
    
    export default function Homepage() {
      const [posts,setPost] = useState([])
      const cookie = new Cookies();
      const token = cookie.get("acsess_token")
    
      const getAll =  async() => {
        const entry = await fetch("/api/entry/entry", {
          headers: {
            "Authorization": token
          }
        })
        
        const data = await entry.json();
        setPost(data)
      }
    
      useEffect(()=> {getAll()})
     
      return (
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <FrindesAdd />
          <div className="w-auto h-auto flex flex-row m-1">
              {posts.map(pod => (
                <Entry>{pod.id} </Entry>
              ))}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What value does `data` have? Probably an object which does not have a `.map()` method.

Comment: `await entry.json()` is probably an object and not an array

Comment: Receives user comments at /entry

Comment: @AtalayÖzyıldırım: "User comments" is not a data type.  The error is telling you that `posts` is not an array (because `.map()` is a function on arrays), so what is `posts`?  Don't focus on what you intuitively call it or what you assume it should be, but debug to observe what it actually is.  After you call `setPost(data)` add a `console.log(data)`.  What gets logged to the console?

Answer (score 1):

Try to map on Object.keys(posts)

```
<div className="w-auto h-auto flex flex-row m-1">
    {Object.keys(posts).map(pod => (
       <Entry>{posts[pod]?.id} </Entry>
    ))}
</div>
```